# Help to modify wp_link_pages()

Tags: php, pagination, paginate-links, wp-link-pages

My site has the Newspaper theme by tagDiv, which installs two necessary plugins to make things work better. These plugins are Composer and Standard Pack.

I'm trying to modify the default `wp_link_pages()` but I don't know how because one of these plugins has code that changes the function.

I don't want to change the plugin file because it is frequently updated. The problem is that the code is not inside a post file like single.php. And I'm not finding a way to do that.

The plugin code is:

[image]

I made this PHP for my own plugin but I don't know how to make it work. I haven't found a way to do this with an action or a filter:

```
function my_new_pagination() {
    if (!is_single()) {
            return '';
        }
        return wp_link_pages(array(
        'next_or_number' => 'next',
        'before' => '<div class="new_pag">',
        'after' => '</div>',
        'nextpagelink' => '<span class="testnav">' . __('Next') . ' »</span>',
        'previouspagelink' => '<span class="testnav">« ' . __('Previous') . '</span>',
        'pagelink' => false,
        'echo' => false
    ));
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: "I don't know how to make it work" - just call your `my_new_pagination()` function from within your template files? But if the `get_post_pagination()` is pluggable (it's wrapped inside a `if ( ! function_exists( 'get_post_pagination' ) )` block), then that means you can override the function from within a child theme, using the `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thanks Sally, I’ll give a try to a child theme.

Comment: Let us know what the solution you ended up using (so that others could benefit from it), but keep in mind, support for 3rd-party themes is off-topic on this site, and you should instead ask in the theme's support forums. :)

Comment: I actually found an easy solution in this [child theme tutorial from tagDiv](https://forum.tagdiv.com/the-child-theme-support-tutorial). It's exactly what I was looking for, I figured out I can change the default single and loop files within the child. Now it's working. Thanks Sally for the hint.